# Building Linq Query Dynamically

Tags: linq, expression-trees

I'm writing LINQ query that implements a keyword-style search. In other words, a query that returns rows whose `Title`,`Description`,`Id` contains

As follows

```
    public static IQueryable<EmployeeObject> QueryableSQL()
    {
        IQueryable<EmployeeObject> queryable = EmployeeRepository.GetAllEmployee(); 
    }

    public static IList<EmployeeObject> QLike(string txt)
    {
       IList<employeeObject> _emps = QueryableSQL().Where(x => x.Title == txt).ToList();
       return _emps;
    }
```

So far, so good. But this only handles the case where you want to match in my case `Title`.

Suppose instead, I wanted to search based on the 'Description`or`Id`should i have to create a new method for Description? or is there a way i can create a`Tree expression`

Comment: Instead of passing in a string text you can pass in a Func<T, bool> and use that in your `.Where()`

Comment: will you show me an example

Comment: Example shown. This would work with any new field you introduce in `EmployeeObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static IQueryable<EmployeeObject> QueryableSQL()
{
    IQueryable<MediaObject> queryable = EmployeeRepository.GetAllEmployee(); 
}

public static IList<EmployeeObject> QLike(Expression<Func<EmployeeObject, bool>> func)
{
   return QueryableSQL().Where(func).ToList();
}
```

You can then call this like:

```
QLike(t => t.Title == "MyText");
```

Comment: Ideally, you should accept a `Expression<Func<EmployeeObject, bool>>` instead of a `Func<EmployeeObject, bool>`.  That will enable the LINQ provider to analyze the predicate and include it as part of the original SQL query.  This can make a huge difference if your unfiltered result set is large.  It could be the difference between reading a million records into memory or reading a single record.

Comment: exactly what i wanted very neat and clean

Comment: @gleng: what does the bool for `Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)? That is, of course if this text may be user provided instead of compiled.

Comment: i have seen that before posting my question and i am not sure how this will fit in my case.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want the property you are comparing against to by dynamic, you could use reflection to do this:

```
public static IList<EmployeeObject> QLike(string propName, string txt)
{
   PropertyInfo filterProp = typeof(EmployeeObject).GetProperty(propName);
   IList<employeeObject> _emps = QueryableSQL().Where(x => filterProp.GetValue(x, null).ToString() == txt).ToList();
   return _emps;
}
```

However the downside to this approach is that you are going to end up loading all of the objects from the database and then filtering them in your code.

If you follow the approach @gleng shows then the Ling to SQL provide will be able to do the filtering in the generated SQL statement. You do need to code the predicates upfront in that case and call the appropriate one based on what property you want to call.